# Add values in column of Panda Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add up the values for a particular column. 
I have a dataframe loaded from CSV that contains the following data:

```
  Date    Item  Count Price per Unit     Sales
0  1/21/16  Unit A     40         $1.50    $60.00
1  1/22/16  Unit A     20         $1.50    $30.00
2  1/23/16  Unit A    100         $1.50   $150.00
```

I want to add up all the sales. I've tried:

```
print sales_df.groupby(["Sales"]).sum()
```

But it's not adding up the sales. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Do you want to sum values from sales? You `Sales` column has a dtype object and `sum` for object (`str`) will be concatenation. Do you need to sum values to get 240?

Comment: Yes, correct, I want the value to be 240. I want sum not concat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you need to sum values from your `Sales` column. First you need to remove `$` with [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace) and then convert to numeric with [`pd.to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html). Then you could use `sum`. One liner:

```
pd.to_numeric(df.Sales.str.replace("$", "")).sum()
```

And step by step:

```
In [35]: df.Sales
Out[35]: 
0     $60.00
1     $30.00
2    $150.00
Name: Sales, dtype: object

In [36]: df.Sales.str.replace("$", "")
Out[36]: 
0     60.00
1     30.00
2    150.00
Name: Sales, dtype: object

In [37]: pd.to_numeric(df.Sales.str.replace("$", ""))
Out[37]: 
0     60
1     30
2    150
Name: Sales, dtype: float64

In [38]: pd.to_numeric(df.Sales.str.replace("$", "")).sum()
Out[38]: 240.0
```

*Note*: `pd.to_numeric` works only with `pandas` version >= `0.17.0`. If you are using older version take a look to `convert_object(convert_numeric=True)`

Comment: Awesome, that works. Thanks for the step-by-step also.

Comment: In your example the column name is hardcoded. How can I rewrite this to have the column be dynamic?

Comment: You could also use `df['Sales']` or `var='Sales'`, `df[var]`